# Airflow: pgpy encrypt gives NotImplementedError: PubKeyAlgorithm.RSAEncrypt error

Tags: python, airflow, pgp

If I execute the following in AWS managed Airflow:

```py
import pgpy
public_key = r'/encryption/pubkey.asc'
key_public, _ = pgpy.PGPKey.from_file(public_key)
key_public._require_usage_flags = False
message = pgpy.PGPMessage.new("42 is quite a pleasant number")
encrypted_message = key_public.encrypt(message)
```

I get the following error:
`NotImplementedError: PubKeyAlgorithm.RSAEncrypt`

Anybody has any ideas why this is happening?

I expected the content to encrypt

Comment: where is public_key getting populated?

Comment: added public_key = '<path>'

Comment: https://github.com/SecurityInnovation/PGPy/issues/323 seems to discuss about it. Appears RSAEncrypt is deprecated in PgPy but need confirmation.
Also, what are my options in pgpy is not able to encrypt using the provided key?